# Can you explain TypeScript 3.7 Optional Chaining?

Tags: javascript, typescript

In TypeScript 3.7.2 I can use Optional Chaining.

```
requests?.requestsCount
```

Can you explain how it works?

```
// before
requests ? requests.requestsCount : 0
// after
requests?.requestsCount || 0
```

I see compiled version of my code.

```
"use strict";
var _a;
return {
    requests: ((_a = requests) === null || _a === void 0 ? void 0 : _a.requestsCount) || 0
};
```

Can you explain `void 0` ? In [release docs](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-3-7/#optional-chaining) it should be undefined.

```js
let x = (foo === null || foo === undefined) ? undefined : foo.bar.baz();
```

May I use this syntactic sugar safely?

Comment: As I understand it, this is short for undefined ?

Comment: `void 0` is, yes.

Comment: But i don't understand this line `(_a = requests)`

Comment: What do you mean, *exactly*? Which parts *do* you understand? That's not a line, it's an assignment expression.

Comment: @jonrsharpe, Assignment moment, why is it here?

Comment: Because if you take it away `_a` will definitely still be `undefined`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202067/discussion-between-polrk-and-jonrsharpe).

Comment: No, thank you. I've linked you to an explanation of `void 0`; if you have another *specific, answerable* question, please [edit] to ask it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This compiled code

```
var _a;
return {
    requests: ((_a = requests) === null || _a === void 0 ? void 0 : _a.requestsCount)
};
```

does the following

```
_a = requests
if _a === null || _a === undefined
    return {requests: undefined}
else
    return {requests: _a.requestsCount}
```

Why `void 0` and not just `undefined`? Because the name `undefined` is not reserved in javascript and can be (in older engines at least) overwritten to something else. `void 0` or `void whatever` is a bullet-proof way to obtain the `undefined` value.

Why the temporary variable `_a` and not just `requests`? Because the compiler has to ensure that the argument is evaluated exactly once. Imagine:

```
someFunc()?.someProp
```

Without the temporary variable this would call `someFunc` three times, which is not acceptable. In the same vein, for longer chains like `x?.y?.z...` the compiler will allocate more temporary variables `_b`, `_c` etc.

I hope this answers your questions.

Comment: Thank you! `Why the temporary variable _a and not just requests?` - I had not known about this until your answer)